# Finding Power Series Representations

Tags: calculus

For *f(x)*, find a power series representation centered at the given value of *a* and determine the radius of convergence.

$$ f(x) = \frac {4x} {x^2-2x-3} ; a=0.$$

How would i begin this?
And what does it mean at the given value of a?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what it means to expand a function into a power series around a point? (It gives you the point; $x=0$...)

Comment: I just know about a function to power series, but not at a given point

Comment: "At a point $a$" just means the series should be of the form $\sum a_n(x-a)^n$.

Comment: Does that mean we sub the value in for a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Start with
$$
\frac {4x} {x^2-2x-3} = \frac {4x}{(x-1)^2-4}
=\frac {x-3+3(x+1)}{(x-3)(x+1)}.
$$

details:

then you get to
$$
 \frac {4x} {x^2-2x-3} = \frac 1{x+1} + \frac 3{x-3}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty -3^{-n}x^n.
$$

Comment: Clever - partial fractions to geometric series.

Comment: How about finding the radius of convergence?

Comment: Also in your last step, is it supposed to be 1/(x+1) not 1/(x-1) ?

Comment: @user136088: I made the appropriate correction

Comment: sorry would the radius of convergence be 1?

Comment: yes! the proper justification: the radius of convergence of the sum of 2 series with *different* radius is $\min(R_1,R_2)$.\

Comment: oh my justification was wrong. but in this case, what would R1 and R2 be?

Comment: 1 for the first term, and 3 for the second (look at the convergence test for a geometric series)